# How to Pass data from one search box to another search box in same component without losing input value in angular 13

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-reactive-forms, angular13, angular-template-form

I need to show the result in second component, the first component is rendered in the second component at the same time i need the user input value to be displayed in the second component for further search

[image]

```html
 **1st component .html**


 <form [formGroup]="jobSearchForm" (ngSubmit)="jobSearchSubmit()">
                <div class="input-group job-group">
                    <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
                        <select class="form-select btn btn-default search-filter-btn" formControlName="versionId">
                            <option *ngFor="let version of versions" value="{{version.code}}">
                                {{version.Name}}
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <span class="input-group-btn search-lbl">
                        <span>
                            <fa-icon [icon]="briefcase" class="job-title-ico"></fa-icon>Job Title
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="name" class="txt-large-search"
                        placeholder="Example: Banking, Insurance and other Financial Clerks">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="searchbtn-lg" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>


**2nd component .html**

    <app-another-component></app-another-component>

  **1st component typescript**

jobSearchSubmit() {
    this.fetchedJobTitleName = this.jobSearchForm.controls.name.value;
    this.fetchedVersionId = this.jobSearchForm.controls.versionId.value;
    this.fetchedDatas = this.jobSearchForm.controls;
this.router.navigate(['search']);
}
```

Comment: So the first component navigates to another component when the user clicks search? Then you want to read the input from the first component in the second, is that correct?

Comment: Since you're navigating to a new component, a solution is to have a new service which is injected into both components. Not sure how familiar you are with rxjs observables but I would consider using them. Something like a `BehaviorSubject` should work.

Comment: Alternatively you can pass the form values as query string params in the search url, which on second thought would probably be the better option

Comment: @AlexW we will get the data using service but we are unable to show it on the input box. 
In the form controls the control.name.value get updated . But unable to view data in the search box